# Which statistics like page visitors or most visited pages are tracked automatically, or do I need extra modules for that?

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm using Drupal 7.22. In this version are there any "default" or *simple site statistics* that are tracked automatically? I am looking for the following statistics:

- Page visitors
- Most visited pages
- Most clicks

Do I have to install a module to get statistics?

Answer (score 5):

Everything in Drupal is provided by a module (core, contrib or custom), so one way or another you'll need to enable one to get extra functionality.

Drupal core comes with a Statistics module, you can enable that and see if it has what you want easily. If not, just search around for the different statistics modules there are out there, and install and try them.

If you stick to stable releases, you shouldn't have any trouble removing a module that you find doesn't do what you need, so there's no downside to trying.

Comment: Thanks @Clive, did not notice it was there, so I'll try that for now.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Google Analytics Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics)

> Adds the Google Analytics web statistics tracking system to your
>   website.
>
> The module allows you to add the following statistics features to your
>   site:
>
> - Single/multi/cross domain tracking
> - Selectively track/exclude certain users, roles and pages
> - Monitor what type of links are tracked (downloads, outgoing and mailto)
> - Monitor what files are downloaded from your pages
> - Custom variables support with tokens
> - Custom code snippets
> - Site Search support
> - AdSense support
> - Demographics and Interests support (formerly known as DoubleClick remarketing support)
> - Anonymize visitors IP address
> - DoNotTrack support (non-cached content only)
> - Drupal messages tracking
> - Modal dialog tracking (Colorbox)
> - Access denied (403) and Page not found (404) tracking
> - Cache the Google Analytics code on your local server for improved page loading times
> - Enhanced Link Attribution support
> - UA: User ID tracking across devices
> - UA: Dimensions and metrics support
> - UA: Changing URL fragments can be tracked as pageviews
> - UA: Debug mode with analytics_debug.js

You'll need a Google Analytics account, but you can Google that.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/project/visitors) **(*)** and [Counter](https://www.drupal.org/project/counter) modules (already mentioned in another answer), here are some other modules that might be a possible fit (quotes are from their project pages):

- [Statistics Advanced](https://www.drupal.org/project/statistics_advanced) **(*)**.

  > Provides a few advanced options to the core Statistics module. Once enabled, these options can be found under "Administer >> Reports >> Access log settings."
- [User Visits](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_visits) (with related [User Visits Advanced](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_visits_adv)).

  > ... tracks visits and referrer from other users on a user's profile page.
  >   It displays the latest visitors on a user's profile page and provides two blocks one with the latest visitors on a user's profile page and one with the latest visitors on own profile page.
  >
  > See [User Visits Advanced](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_visits_adv) for additional functionality.
- [Better Statistics](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_statistics).

  > ... introduces a Statistics API, allowing developers and contributed modules a way to collect, limit, and route custom access statistics and data.
- [Node view count](https://drupal.org/project/nodeviewcount).

  > ... allows to count node views. Unlike statistics module, this module records each view of node with user uid and timestamp. So now you can know how many times a user viewed node by day, week, month and etc.
  >
  > This module is integrated with Views module. You can use it to create different statistics pages, output new not viewed nodes for user and many more.

Disclosure: I'm the maintainer of the modules marked with **(*)**.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in comments that you need simple stats statistics like page visitors, most visited pages, most clicks So check out these modules.

[Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/project/visitors)

> This module used for displaying a visitors info.

[Counter](https://www.drupal.org/project/counter)

> Counter module counts how many visitors on your website. This module provides real time counting. All data saved to database.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is *Do I have to install a module to get statistics?*, the answer is no. If you have a Google account, you can simply copy and paste a [Google Analytics code snippet](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/?hl=en) into your theme's html.tpl.php.

However the [Google Analytics module](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics) is generally the preferred option since it provides robust configuration options for site administrators via the administration UI.

More information on overriding template files can be found here:

- [Theming guide: Core templates | Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/190815)
- [html.tpl.php | Drupal API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!html.tpl.php/7)